# How two separate webapi projects can share same base Url

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7, azure-web-app-service

I have two webapi projects hosted on two separate azure websites. Is there a way i can have same base url for both? One project is actually OAuth auth server which i want to access

```
http:\\abc.azurewebsites.net/oauth instead of
http:\\myoauth.azurewebsites.net
```

any help?

Comment: Do we have a separate url for OAuth server? or it should share same base url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way DNS works, the url can only point to one website.

However, can modify one of your site to act as a Reverse Proxy for the oauth urls. Then all requests to the oauth urls will be redirected to your second site.

Setting up a reverse proxy for some urls is a config only change. Add the following to your applicationHost.xdt file:

```
<configuration>  
 <system.webServer>  
  <rewrite>  
   <rules>  
    <rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">  
     <match url="^proxy/?(.*)" />  
     <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.iis.net/{R:1}" />  
    </rule>  
   </rules>  
  </rewrite>  
 </system.webServer>
```

You can find full instructions here: http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/